# FilePrint doesn't print file when running on Wolfram Programming Cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

As simple as it sounds, I do some writing to a file and then close it. Afterwards I run `FilePrint[foo]` but nothing shows up when running on the cloud, whereas when running on desktop, it does.

Ideas?

#### EDIT

Here's the code. It's silly though.

---

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[ {"Image" -> "Image", "Scale"->"Number" },
  Module[{},
    x=#Image;
    r = #Scale;
    ig = ColorConvert[x, "Grayscale"];
    str = OpenWrite["imgg.txt"];
    CloudExport[x, "JPG", "file"];
    x = Part[ImageDimensions[ig], 2];
    y = Part[ImageDimensions[ig], 1];
    kx = 2 r;
    ky = r;
    sx = x/kx;
    sy = y/ky;
    chars = {" ", ".", ",", ":",";","-","=", "+", "*","x", "#","%","X", "@"};
    f[z_] := chars[[Length[chars] - Floor[(Length[chars] - 1) z/255]]];
    Do[
      Do[
        WriteString[
          str,
          f[
            N[
              Mean[
                Mean[
                  ImageData[
                    ImageTake[ig, {kx*j, kx (j + 1)}, {ky*i, ky (i + 1)}], 
                    "Byte"]]], 
               3]]], 
        {i, 0, sy}]
        WriteString[str, "\n"],
      {j, 0, sx}];
    Close[str];]&, AppearanceRules -> {"Title" -> "IMG-2-ASCII"}]]
```

---

The following is a sample input and a sample output (image and the content of the file respectively).

**Input**

[image: Random Google Image]

**Output**

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-=+**xxxxxxx+=-;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;=*#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#x*+=-;;;:::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-*#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#=;;:::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;*%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%###%%%%%%#-;;::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%##%%%%%#%#%%*;;;:::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;=#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%###%#%%%=;;;::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#xx**++++**x###%%%x;;;::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;x%%%%%%%%%%%%x+-;;;;;;::;-+x##%%%%%x;;;:::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;x%%%%%%%%%%%#+;::::::::::::;-x##%%%%%=;;;::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;+%%%%%%%%%#%%x-;;;;;:::::::::;;-*%%%%%x-;;::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;=#%%%%%%%%%%%%x=;;;;;::::::::::;;=#%%%%%+;;;:::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;x%%%%%%%%%%%%%#+-;:::::::::::::;-=+%%%%%x-;;:::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;=%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#+--;;::::::;-++**+==*%%%%+-;::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-*#%%%%%%%%%%%%#x##%%#x=;::;;+x#%xx+;-##%%=;;;:::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-x#%%%%%%%%%%%#x#x*x*=*=-;::;----;:;;-*%%%=;;;:::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;+##%%%%%%%%%%%#+-;;;;;---;::;;::::::;-;x%#-;;::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-*x%%%%%%%%%%%%x=;:::::;;;;::::::::::;-+#%x-;;::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;*x#%%%%%%%%%##%x=;;::;;;;;;:::::;;::::;x%x=-;;::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-x##%%%%%%%%%%%%%*=-;;;--;;--;;::::;--;;;x%+-;;:::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;+#%%%%#%%%%%%%%%%*=--==--;;;;;;;;;==:;;:=%+=;;::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;x%%%%%%%%%%#%%%%%#+----=x*---;;:::=;::;+x-;;;:::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;=%###%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%*=;-;-==-;:::;;:::;*x=;;;::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;x#x##%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%x+-;;;---;;;;::::=+*;;::::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-x##%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%x*+=;;;::::::::::-----;;::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;**#%%%%%%%%#%%%%%%%%%%#*++=-;;::::::::;-::;---;:::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;+xx#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%###x+==--;;;;;;;:::;-;:;;;;:::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;+###%%%%%%%%%%%#xxx**##x**+=-;;;:::::::::::=+;::::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;+##%%%%%%%%%%%%#+=x#x*=+==-----;:::::::;:::::=#-:::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;-*##%%%%%%%%%%%%#*+==---:---;;;;;::::::::;::;;::=%+;:::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;=x#%%%%%%%%%%%%%x=--;;;;-;:;:::::::::::::::::;;;;:-#=;;:::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;-+%%%%%%%%%%%##%%*=;;;;;:;;-:::::::::::::::::::;;;;;;-#-::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;-x%#%#%%%%%%%%*#%*-;;;::::::;;:::::::;;;:::::::::;;;;;;-#+;::::::::::
;;;;;;;=x##%####%%%#x%*%#=-;;;:::::::;;;;::;::::::::::::::;;;;;;=%x;:::::::::
;;;;;;=**####**#%%x=-%%%x=-;;;::::::::-::::::::::::::::::::;:::;;+%*::;::::::
;;;;;=+=*x#x**x%%x=--#%%+-;;;;;;;;;;;-+;-;;;::::::::::::::::::::;;*%+::::::::
;;;;;==*xx+==*%%x=-;+%%#=--;;;;;--;-=xx=+;;-;::::::::::::::::::::;-#x;::::;;;
;;--+*x*==-=*%%x=--+###x=----------=*#*-**--=;-=*=;:::::::::::::::;*=;::;:;;;
:==*x#=--;=+x%%*-;-x#xx*-----------=*#*-*##%%xx+*%X;::::::::;::::::=-=;:::;;+
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed, but simple, example of what you did. This might be an issue with file paths and directories that are treated differently in the cloud than on the desktop.

Comment: I've made an (relevant?) edit. Is that good enough?

Comment: Your code appears to have a missing semicolon (;) between the expression `Do[ ... {i, 0, sy}]` and the expression `WriteString[str, "\n"]`. That's bound to be causing trouble although I don't fixing it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `Print[]` doesn't print to the output screen of the user. A workaround I found was to `Import[]` and show the string with some formatting.

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[ {"Image" -> "Image", "Scale"->"Number" },
  Module[{},
    x=#Image;
    r = #Scale;
    ig = ColorConvert[x, "Grayscale"];
    str = OpenWrite["imgg.txt"];
    CloudExport[x, "JPG", "file"];
    x = Part[ImageDimensions[ig], 2];
    y = Part[ImageDimensions[ig], 1];
    kx = 2 r;
    ky = r;
    sx = x/kx;
    sy = y/ky;
    chars = {" ", ".", ",", ":",";","-","=", "+", "*","x", "#","%","X", "@"};
    f[z_] := chars[[Length[chars] - Floor[(Length[chars] - 1) z/255]]];
    Do[
      Do[
        WriteString[
          str,
          f[
            N[
              Mean[
                Mean[
                  ImageData[
                    ImageTake[ig, {kx*j, kx (j + 1)}, {ky*i, ky (i + 1)}], 
                    "Byte"]]], 
               3]]], 
        {i, 0, sy}];
        WriteString[str, "\n"],
      {j, 0, sx}];
   Close[str];
   s = Import["imgg.txt"];
   ExportForm[Style[
s, Black,
FontFamily -> "American Typewriter"], "String"]
   ]&, AppearanceRules -> {"Title" -> "Image 2 ASCII"}]]
```